# Kile runs very slow under ubuntu, when expending the structure

Tags: ubuntu, latex

Do any one has the same problem? I am using Ubuntu+Kile for latex. Whenever I save file, the structure side window expands twice, and it is very slow. Do anyone know how to solve this problem?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run Kile from the commandline and look for Debugging outputs during your problematic operations? This could give you some hints.
I found not much about kile commandline parameters, but you can try to append -v or --verbose to get more verbose info.